# dynamically adding images to a list box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, listbox

I have a WPF application that has a vertical listbox that I would like to programmaticly add images to.  I want to be able to use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor the directory that the photos are in and when a new image is added or an image is deleted the list box will update the images in the application.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very roughly, you bind the `ItemsSource` property of the ListBox to an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) of images. Have your watcher process add images to the collection as they appear, and databinding should cause the ListBox to be updated as the backing collection changes.

Further: [How to: Create and Bind to an ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx)

That's the general concept. Can't get much more specific than that without knowing anything about your code. :) Good luck!